# PHP Multipage form session data being lost after 2 navigations

Tags: php, html, forms, multipage

I have a multipage form site that I am building.

I am using

```
$_SESSION['X']=$_POST['X']
```

to store variables from the form into sessions on the page the results are being posted to.

The form is dynamically generated so that the fields are populated with the session variables

```
$X=$_SESSION['X']
```

and

```
(value="$X")
```

This way when a user clicks back (a button with a page URL, not a history -1) the page is reformed with the values they previously entered.

My problems is that this works fine for one page (i.e. they can go back one page and see values), but 2 pages all values are blank.

Once values are stored in a SESSION shouldn't they stay for the duration of the browser session? They are not being overwritten. Am I misunderstanding session? Any help appreciated.

Code example:

Page 1:

```
session_start();

//populates fields if session value set for this variable 
$sv_01=$_SESSION['sv_01'];

<<<EOT
<form action="page 2 URL" method="post">
<label> q1 <input value=$sv_01 title="title" type="text" name="sv_01">

<input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
EOT;
```

Page 2:

```
session_start();
//stores POST data from page 1 in the session
$_SESSION['sv_01']=$_POST['sv_01']

//populates fields if session value set for this variable 
$sv_02=$_SESSION['sv_02'];

<<<EOT
<form action="page 3 URL" method="post">
<label> q2 <input value=$sv_02 title="title" type="text" name="sv_02">

<input onclick="page 1 URL';" type="button" value="Back" /> <input type="submit" value="Continue" />    
</form>
EOT;
```

Page 3:

```
session_start();
//stores POST data from page 2 in the session
$_SESSION['sv_02']=$_POST['sv_02']

//populates fields if session value set for this variable 
$sv_03=$_SESSION['sv_03'];

<<<EOT
<form action="page 4 URL" method="post">
<label> q3 <input value=$sv_03 title="title" type="text" name="sv_03">

<input onclick="page 2 URL';" type="button" value="Back" /> <input type="submit" value="Continue" />    
</form>
EOT;
```

Moving from page 3 to 2 would be fine - and page 2 to 1 also, but moving from page 3 to 1 would result in page 1 being blank.

Any ideas? Much appreciated

Comment: All vars are blank when you go back to the first page?

Comment: I don't see any reason in the example you showed us above, why that would happen, but you should check if a session is set before using it anyway, also, empty how? are all empty? can you do a print_r of the $_SESSION, are you sure you jump from page 3 to 1 ? Because you could be setting session 1 to nothing, due to the session1=post1 on your 2nd page, which you do not verifiy if there was a post, and etc.

Comment: @MarcioSimao yes all vars blank when I go back to first page

Comment: @AndréCatita note that I don't jump directly from page 3 to page 1, I go back via page 2 - however there is nothing on page 2 which would resubmit the values of the varibles to the session so should be fine? Not sure I understand about setting it to nothing but perhaps it relates to the answer below... will try that and also a print_r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are overwriting the `$_SESSION` var with a `NULL` value that comes from `$_POST`, because if you are jumping from Page3.php to Page2.php using a link the `$_POST` content doesn't exist.

So you can solve this verifying if the `$_POST` value exists before assign its value to `$_SESSION`. Something like this code:

**Page 2.php**

```
if( isset($_POST['sv_01'])
    $_SESSION['sv_01']=$_POST['sv_01'];
```

**Page 3.php**

```
if( isset($_POST['sv_02']) )
    $_SESSION['sv_02']=$_POST['sv_02'];
```

Comment: Fantastic - this was exactly it. I'll select your answer as it had a slightly clearer statement of why it broke it than @user1404632 below. Thankful to you both though!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try checking that the $_POST members are set first.

Instead of:

```
$_SESSION['sv_01']=$_POST['sv_01']
```

Try

```
if (isset($_POST['sv_01'])) {
  $_SESSION['sv_01']=$_POST['sv_01']
}
```